# Can I use a capacitive divider to run an AC/DC converter from a higher voltage than its rating?

Tags: capacitor, ac, voltage-divider, converter, load

Suppose I have an AC/DC converter rated to run from 120-240VAC, and I want to run it off 480 VAC. I think I should be able to put two capacitors in series as a voltage divider, and run the converter off the lower voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAlsc5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One problem I see is that the load of the power supply will cause the voltage on the supply terminals to drop. The bigger C1 is (and presumably C2 to maintain the divider ratio), the less this effect will be. The other issue is that the capacitors may need to be X-class for UL purposes. For an example 10W converter, I'm getting numbers in the 1-5 uF range, which is easily obtainable.

Am I missing anything? Is this a terrible idea for reasons I'm not seeing?

Comment: This is more than likely a terrible idea for safety reasons, among others. Use a control transformer!

Comment: @SpheroPefhany I agree that that's the preferred solution. But do you know where I can get a 480->240 10 VA board-mount UL-rated control transformer?

Comment: I would *definitely* only use X-class capacitors for this. And then I would be *sure as hell* that U2 was an isolated converter. And then I would pot the whole damn thing.

Comment: Consider what happens if C2 fails open circuit or C1 fails short circuit. Can you protect U2 in both of these eventualities? Something like overvoltage detection, crowbar, and fuse...

Comment: What if the ACDC convertor has inductance and tunes on the caps giving a totally wrong outputvolts and what about the source impedence of the caps , unless the caps are big the convertor may go unstable.IN fact the caps could end up bigger than a transformer .What about the power factor .

Comment: @BrianDrummond If I'm using X-class capacitors, failing open or short shouldn't be a concern, at least no more a concern than an equivalent transformer failing with some windings shorted.

Comment: @Autistic The caps could certainly be larger than an equivalent transformer, but sourcing an equivalent transformer isn't necessarily trivial. Power factor isn't really a concern at 10W in my context. I'm not sure I understand your other points.

Comment: Such capacitive dividers have been used in some applications (vintage nicad chargers).  Usually if the power required if small (10W is not quite trivial for board mounted components) it is possible.  Also if the line frequency is constant then a Cap Resistor circuit may be an option. Also a Cap Zenner circuit may work.  A constant load will make everything work more predictably as well.  Failure in components is a real concern, use two caps, zenner diodes or resistors in series to mitigate a single component short, have a fuse and over voltage protection in case of open circuits.